Cross out if no table entry in a longtable environment
I changed a command from "Heiko Oberdiek" (Strike out a table cell) a little bit and it works fine in the standard tabular environment.
\newcounter{NoTableEntry}
\renewcommand*{\theNoTableEntry}{NTE-\the\value{NoTableEntry}}

\newcommand*{\notableentry}{%
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}|}{%
    \stepcounter{NoTableEntry}%
    \vadjust pre{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry t}}% 
    \vadjust{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry b}}% 
    \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry l}% 
    \hspace{0pt plus 1filll}%
    \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry r}% 
    \tikz[overlay]{%
      \draw[black]
        let
          \n{llx}={\zposx{\theNoTableEntry l}sp-\zposx{\theNoTableEntry r}sp},
          \n{urx}={0},
          \n{lly}={\zposy{\theNoTableEntry b}sp-\zposy{\theNoTableEntry r}sp},
          \n{ury}={\zposy{\theNoTableEntry t}sp-\zposy{\theNoTableEntry r}sp}
        in
        (\n{llx}, \n{ury}) -- (\n{urx}, \n{lly})
      ;
    }% 
  }%
}

But I also need it in longtables. If the the table breaks and in the first line of the table on next page is a \notableentry, it will save the position of the last page on the bottom where the new cell should begin and my line go through the whole page.

\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\newcounter{NoTableEntry}
\renewcommand*{\theNoTableEntry}{NTE-\the\value{NoTableEntry}}
\newcommand*{\notableentry}{%
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}|}{%
    \stepcounter{NoTableEntry}%
    \vadjust pre{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry t}}% 
    \vadjust{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry b}}% 
    \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry l}% 
    \hspace{0pt plus 1filll}%
    \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry r}% 
    \tikz[overlay]{%
      \draw[black]
        let
          \n{llx}={\zposx{\theNoTableEntry l}sp-\zposx{\theNoTableEntry r}sp},
          \n{urx}={0},
          \n{lly}={\zposy{\theNoTableEntry b}sp-\zposy{\theNoTableEntry r}sp},
          \n{ury}={\zposy{\theNoTableEntry t}sp-\zposy{\theNoTableEntry r}sp}
        in
        (\n{llx}, \n{ury}) -- (\n{urx}, \n{lly})
      ;
    }% 
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\hbox{}
\par\vspace{17.5cm }
    \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
    \hhline{|-|-|-|}
      R0 & Table entry  & Table entry  \\
      \hhline{|-|-|-|}
      
  \endfirsthead
  \hhline{|-|-|-|}
    R0 & Table entry  & Table entry  \\
    \hhline{|-|-|-|}
    
  \endhead
    \multicolumn{3}{r}{to be continued on next Page}
  \endfoot
  \endlastfoot
       R1 & \notableentry  & Table entry\\
     \hhline{|-|-|-|}
     R2  & Table entry & \notableentry \\
     \hhline{|-|-|-|}
      R3& Table entry  & Table entry  \\
     \hhline{|-|-|-|}
       R4& \notableentry  & Table entry\\
     \hhline{|-|-|-|}
        R5& Table entry & \notableentry \\
     \hhline{|-|-|-|}
       R6& Table entry  & Table entry  \\
     \hhline{|-|-|-|}
       R7& \notableentry  & Table entry\\
     \hhline{|-|-|-|}
        R8& Table entry & \notableentry \\
         \hhline{|-|-|-|}
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}

Any ideas how to make it also for longtables viable?
Best regards
Viggo

If someone have the same issue:
I switched from longtable to supertabular. With that it works fine.

\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{supertabular}


\newcounter{NoTableEntry}
\renewcommand*{\theNoTableEntry}{NTE-\the\value{NoTableEntry}}
\newcommand*{\notableentry}{%
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}|}{%
    \stepcounter{NoTableEntry}%
    \vadjust pre{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry t}}% 
    \vadjust{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry b}}% 
    \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry l}% 
    \hspace{0pt plus 1filll}%
    \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry r}% 
    \tikz[overlay]{%
      \draw[black]
        let
          \n{llx}={\zposx{\theNoTableEntry l}sp-\zposx{\theNoTableEntry r}sp},
          \n{urx}={0},
          \n{lly}={\zposy{\theNoTableEntry b}sp-\zposy{\theNoTableEntry r}sp},
          \n{ury}={\zposy{\theNoTableEntry t}sp-\zposy{\theNoTableEntry r}sp}
        in
        (\n{llx}, \n{ury}) -- (\n{urx}, \n{lly})
      ;
    }% 
  }%
}
\begin{document}


\hbox{}
\par\vspace{17.5cm }


\begin{center}
\tablefirsthead{%
    \hhline{|-|-|-|}
      R0 & Table entry  & Table entry  \\
      \hhline{|-|-|-|}
}
\tablehead{%
  \hhline{|-|-|-|}
    R0 & Table entry  & Table entry  \\
}
\tabletail{%
\hhline{|-|-|-|}
\multicolumn{3}{r}{to be continued on next Page}\\
}
\tablelasttail{}
\begin{supertabular}{|c|c|c|}
   R1 & \notableentry  & Table entry\\
 \hhline{|-|-|-|}
 R2  & Table entry & \notableentry \\
 \hhline{|-|-|-|}
  R3& Table entry  & Table entry  \\
 \hhline{|-|-|-|}
   R4& \notableentry  & Table entry\\
 \hhline{|-|-|-|}
    R5& Table entry & \notableentry \\
 \hhline{|-|-|-|}
   R6& Table entry  & Table entry  \\
 \hhline{|-|-|-|}
   R7& \notableentry  & Table entry\\
 \hhline{|-|-|-|}
    R8& Table entry & \notableentry \\
     \hhline{|-|-|-|}
\end{supertabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}

